# sql primary_key doesnt work?

Tags: php, sql, key

i am currently working on a registration script for my website, and i noticed that when i register i can resubmit the form over and over and i have no idea why nothing stops me. i mean, here's the PHP script to use to see if a user already exsists:

```
function user_exists($username) {
$query = mysql_query("SELECT username FROM users WHERE username='$username'");
if (mysql_num_rows($query) != 0){
  return true;
 }
else{
return false;
}
}
```

and heres the SQL code i used to create the table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
`user_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`username` varchar(32) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`password` varchar(128) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`email` varchar(1024) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`active` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`ip` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0.0.0',
`date` varchar(64) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=61 ;
```

so if anyone could help me with this, any help will be appriciated.

Comment: What calls `user_exists`? What does it do with the `true`/`false` it gets?

Comment: Are you creating errors to be displayed, if a username is already taken?

Comment: If you are comfortable with JS/AJAX, I would use Javascript to call your PHP function and check if the username already exists, if so then prevent the user from submitting the form.

Comment: @Mewbi3 Yes, if true returned, the registration is stopped, user is supposed to be notified, if false, it passes to the next step.

Answer (score 0):

this has nothing to do with answering your question, but everything to do with improving your ability to quickly write efficient & well written code:

your way:

```
function user_exists($username) {
$query = mysql_query("SELECT username FROM users WHERE username='$username'");
if (mysql_num_rows($query) != 0){
  return true;
 }
else{
return false;
}
}
```

better written way:

```
function user_exists($username) {
  $query = mysql_query("SELECT username FROM users WHERE username='$username'");
  if(mysql_num_rows($query) > 0) return true;
  return false;
}
```

sql statement seems fine, as long as you are calling your function and testing it properly it should work. although unless you are sanitizing your $username input before calling user_exists, you have a gaping security exploit right there ;)

Comment: Nope, it still registeres a user despite it already being registered, it returns a success message and inserts it's data to the table.here's how i call the function:
    `if(user_exists($_POST['username'] == true)){
    $errors[] = "Username already registered.";
    }`

Comment: oh that's it, you are calling it wrong. it should be simply: if(user_exists($_POST['username'])) { $errors[] = "Username already registered."; }

Comment: *facepalm* i am an idiot, it worked, i just called the function in the wrong way, as you said.

Comment: haha it happens. just make sure you sanitize your database input before the $query is executed or you are really asking for trouble in the long run ;)

Comment: and how would i do that?

Comment: use mysql_real_escape_string: http://us.php.net/mysql_real_escape_string - or switch to using prepared statements instead (google PDO or mysqli prepared statements)

Comment: Your "better" way would be better still as just `return mysql_num_rows($query) > 0;`

Comment: you're right Niet, but I didn't want to overcomplicate the concept for him. some people need baby steps before they can go to outright short-handing everything.

Answer (score 0):

I see a couple of problems in your code snippet.

1) The way that you are calling your user_exists() function, you are passing "true" as the username each time you call it. You have...

```
if (user_exists($_POST['username'] == true)) { 
    $errors[] = "Username already registered."; 
}
```

So the actual query you are running is...

```
SELECT username FROM users WHERE username='1';
```

Should be...

```
if (user_exists($_POST['username'])) { 
    $errors[] = "Username already registered."; 
}
```

2) You are missing a parameter when you call mysql_query(). There should be a second parameter with the connection.

```
$query = mysql_query($"SELECT userName FROM csg.user WHERE userName='$username'",$con);
```